# Does or can the server send the client all the page resources at once to save time?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, http, server

From the articles and documentation I've read, mostly from Google Chrome engineers, page load times are high because of large file sizes and multiple HTTP requests. The HTML page has to be read by the browser and as the browser finds external resources, it loads them one by one; images, scripts, stylesheets, etc.

Has anyone thought of packaging up all the resources into a zip file to send that one resource? I know there are issues with that with things like dynamic imports and so on but I think those issues could be solved. You could have traditional method where all the resources are on the file system and served traditionally and an alternative response type where a zip file that has all the resources are sent in one bundle.

A downside could be on slow connections you wouldn't get any plain text preview that's as you are right in the middle of reading it is replaced with the styled content. However, that could be solved, possibly, by placing the HTML at the beginning of the stream (if zipped files can do that). Also, I know that assets are individually gzipped before being sent to the browser. This suggestion would be to have the entire resource in one zip.

Also, the server could do this process now by reading the HTML page, and matching for external resources. It wouldn't catch all resources (well maybe it could if it spun up an instance of the exact same browser as the client). If it was a real feature web authors could mention in their web page all the files to include in a bundle.

If the resources are static I can see only benefits.

The question is if web servers have any existing feature set that will send the entire page content in one network request (and I guess browsers will have to support reading that bundle on the client).

Comment: This is a big driving factor behind bundlers like `webpack`. Can you elaborate as to what would constitute an acceptable answer to your question? This seems to be framed more like a discussion than a Q&A that would be considered on-topic here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/3 is intended to help with the multiple resources issues.

Comment: @esqew I've specified the question in the post

Comment: @ceejayoz from wikipedia, "HTTP/3 uses similar semantics compared to earlier revisions of the protocol but encodes them and maintains session state differently." It looks like that's the QUIC component and iiuc it sends back multiple resources in parallel instead of sequentially?

Comment: Sounds like graphql to me and ssr